What happens when you missout an argument to the printf function
The following code prints out the Celsius equivalent of Fahrenheit temperatures from 0 to 300 with 20 as step.
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int fahr, celsius;
    int lower, upper, step;

    lower = 0;
    upper = 300;
    step = 20;

    fahr = lower;

    while (fahr <= upper) {
        celsius = 5 * (fahr - 32) / 9;
        printf("%d\t%d\n", fahr, celsius);
        fahr = fahr + step;
    }

    return 0;
}

It prints out the expected result as follows.

When I leave out an argument from the printf function as printf("%d\t%d\n", fahr); , it gives the following output.

The modified program gives the same (expected) output except for the first two values. Is there a specific reason for this behavior or is it random?

It's undefined behavior. You should get a compiler warning -- and if not, you should enable compiler warnings. Probably you're seeing some value off the stack or in a register, which often happens to be celsius, but I guess if you change the optimization level you'll get something else.

It's an accident — you can't rely on it 'working'.  It's undefined behaviour, as already noted.  Turn up the compiler warnings so that the faulty code does not compile.  If you use GCC, use -Werror -Wall -Wextra as a starter set of options.

Most likely, the division was implemented by first dividing rounding down, and then adding 1 if needed to make it round towards zero. And the result of the first step happened to be placed in the register that got printed. But this can't be relied upon.

@PaulHankin yes, I have compiler warnings enabled and I do get warnings. I intentionally left out the argument to see what would happen to the output. Thanks.

At run-time each format specifier is assumed to be the truth, and the code has the data where it is expected it to be. It will have no idea that arguments provided to the compiler were faulty, but it will do something anyway, which may crash the code (for example a faulty string pointer that tries to access illegal memory).

@uj95 Aside: celsius = 5 * (fahr - 32) / 9; truncates the fraction part during the  division.   To get an integer  rounded result, consider int prod = 10 * (fahr - 32); celsius = (prod + (prod < 0 ? -9 : 9)) / 18; or the like.
